# Automatically Restore Previous Version of a Google Document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I work in a school, and have teachers fill out a point chart every week in google sheets. At the end of the week, I save the information and restore the sheet to it's blank state as it was at the beginning of the week.

I'm looking for an add-on that will automatically restore a previous version of my sheet on a weekly basis at a certain time. Have you ever come across an add-on that does something similar?

Answer (score 1):

For this you can write an Apps script function with the content below:

```
// This example assumes there is a sheet named "first"
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var first = ss.getSheetByName("first");
 first.clearContents();
```

And add a [time driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to that function to run once a week.

Hope that helps!